# Tkinter Entry Widgets in list all saving same data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function called `display_change` that is in the middle of my tkinter GUI. I want the user to select a number and create the number of entry boxes that they select. I figured out how to do this with a for loop and putting each entry box into a list. However whenever I write something the same data is saved between all of the entry widgets.

I don't want to show all my code but can show the whole function that this is happening in.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button
labels = []
entries = []

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.mainFrame()

    def mainFrame(self):
        self.master.title("Setup")
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Follow the instructions on each page", bg="snow2")
        lbl.grid(sticky=tk.W, pady=4, padx=5)

        area = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=4,
              padx=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.S + tk.N)

        # ----------Inside White Box ---------------------
        lbl = tk.Label(area, text="Select the number of parts to create:")
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

        choices = {0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

        node_count = tk.IntVar()
        node_count.set(0)
        node_select = tk.OptionMenu(area, node_count, *choices,
                                command=lambda x: self.display_change(area, node_count.get()))
        node_select.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # -----------Outside Part-------------------------
        abtn = Button(self, text="Thing 1")
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        cbtn = Button(self, text="Thing 2")
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4, sticky=tk.W)

        abtn2 = Button(self, text="Thing 3")
        abtn2.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=tk.W + tk.N)

        cbtn2 = Button(self, text="Thing 4")
        cbtn2.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=28, sticky=tk.W + tk.N)

        hbtn = Button(self, text="Exit")
        hbtn.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

        sbtn = Button(self, text="Save")
        sbtn.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=3, sticky=tk.W)

        sbtn = Button(self, text="Help")
        sbtn.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    def display_change(self, area, nodes):
        """Here is where the display is changed so what the user choose is correctly displayed"""

        lower_label = tk.Label(area, text="Enter the value of each part")
        lower_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W)

        global labels, entries
        for label in labels:
            label.destroy()
        for entry in entries:
            entry.destroy()
        labels = []
        entries = []

        # This loop creates the correct number of entry box's and labels. Each entry is stored separately
        for i in range(nodes):
            if nodes <= 4:
                labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="Part "+str(i+1)))
                labels[i].place(x=10+(120*i), y=55)
                entries.append(tk.Entry(area, text="Change"))
                entries[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=80, width=100)
            else:
                labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="part " + str(i + 1)))
                labels[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=105)
                entries.append(tk.Entry(area, text="Change"))
                entries[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=160, width=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()

"""Calculate center of screen so popup is center"""
w = 650
h = 400

ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

# This line prevents the user from changing the size of the window
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is what it looks like when I type something:[image]

All I typed was 'abcd' once but it went into all the entries

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as there is not enough code here to test your problem. You have a method from a class but we also need the class itself.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I have tested this code outside of a class and it still produces the same problem. I am not sure why each entry field would bet getting the same input from the keyboard though. I have used list in this way in the past without this kind of problem.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I added a little more code to try and help, like you asked

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry for the confusion. I was not saying you were wrong or anything. I was just asking if you had any idea as to what is causing this kind of bug. To me it looks like a bug or I am missing something.

Comment: BTW, you should not mix layout mangers in the one container. So you can't use `.grid` for some widgets in a Frame and then `.place` for other widgets in that same Frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at all the available [config](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method) options in the documentation for tkinters Entry field `text` is not one of them. Most likely because `textvariable` is an available argument for the Entry field tkinter is seeing `text` as short for `textvariable`. So as a result what is happening is all of your Entry fields are being assigned the same text variable and when one entry changes that variable all of them update with the new string in that variable.

The correct way to write your for loop would be something like the following:

```
for i in range(nodes):
    if nodes  <= 4:
        labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="Part {}".format(i+1)))
        labels[i].place(x=10+(120*i), y=55)
        entries.append(tk.Entry(area))
        entries[i].insert(0, "Change Ip") # adds text directly to an entry field
        entries[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=80, width=100)
    else:
        labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="Node {}".format(i+1)))
        labels[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=105)
        entries.append(tk.Entry(area)
        entries[i].insert(0, "Change Ip")
        entries[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=160, width=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it completely, but the text keyword argument is associating all of the entries with the same string variable that is then stored and simultaneously updating everything.

Instead of passing the text keyword, you can use the "insert" method of the entry after instantiation to set the text in the entry.

Tkinter doesn't have the best documentation in the world, so I'm not totally sure what's going on with the text keyword.  Will keep looking into it.  Here is an MVCE that does not exhibit the problematic behavior:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button
labels = []
entries = []

def display_change(self, area, nodes):
    """Here is where the display is changed so what the user choose is correctly seen"""

    lower_label = tk.Label(area, text="Enter the value of each part")
    lower_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W)

    global labels, entries
    for label in labels:
        label.destroy()
    for entry in entries:
        entry.destroy()
    labels = []
    entries = []

    # This loop creates the correct number of entry box's and labels. Each entry is stored separately
    for i in range(nodes):
        if nodes <= 4:
            labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="Part "+str(i+1)))
            labels[i].place(x=10+(120*i), y=55)
            entries.append(tk.Entry(area))
            entries[i].insert(0, "Change IP")
            entries[i].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=80, width=100)

root = tk.Tk()

display_change(None, root, 4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are correct about how to set up the Entry fields but your answer includes other things that should be avoided. The way you are calling the function that contains self does work but as a stand alone function it should not be using self in the first place. If you are going to use it as a proper class method then you should provide an example using a class to support the method. The best way to provide an answer to the OP before they updated their code in the question would be to just provide the correct method in the for loop and explain why it works.

Comment: In the interests of time, I simply copied the code that was there and added the necessary bits to make it work as an MVCE

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `Entry` widgets don't have a `text` option, which is why the initial value they display isn't `"Change Ip"`. `Entry` widgets do have a `textvariable` option, which must be be set to a `StringVar` for you to be able retrieve the current text from it later using a `var.get()` call.

Below is a runnable version of your code that shows an example of how to do this in the `display_change()` method. An new global list has been added named `textvars` to hold the `StringVar`s that go with each `Entry` widget. You can use entries in it to get the current text in each corresponding `Entry`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button

labels = []
entries = []
textvars = []

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.mainFrame()

    def mainFrame(self):
        self.master.title("Tinc VM Setup")
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Follow the instructions on each page",
                       bg="snow2")
        lbl.grid(sticky=tk.W, pady=4, padx=5)

        area = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=4,
              padx=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.S + tk.N)

        # ----------Inside White Box ---------------------
        lbl = tk.Label(area, text="Select the number of parts to create:")
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

        choices = {0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

        node_count = tk.IntVar()
        node_count.set(0)
        node_select = tk.OptionMenu(area, node_count, *choices,
            command=lambda x: self.display_change(area, node_count.get()))
        node_select.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # -----------Outside Part-------------------------
        abtn = Button(self, text="Thing 1")
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        cbtn = Button(self, text="Thing 2")
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4, sticky=tk.W)

        abtn2 = Button(self, text="Thing 3")
        abtn2.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=tk.W + tk.N)

        cbtn2 = Button(self, text="Thing 4")
        cbtn2.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=28, sticky=tk.W + tk.N)

        hbtn = Button(self, text="Exit")
        hbtn.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

        sbtn = Button(self, text="Save")
        sbtn.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=3, sticky=tk.W)

        sbtn = Button(self, text="Help")
        sbtn.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    def display_change(self, area, nodes):
        """Here is where the display is changed so what the user choose is
           correctly displayed.
        """
        lower_label = tk.Label(area, text="Enter the value of each part")
        lower_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W)

        global labels, entries, textvars
        for label in labels:
            label.destroy()
        for entry in entries:
            entry.destroy()
        labels = []
        entries = []
        textvars = []

        # This loop creates the correct number of entry box's and labels.
        # Each entry is stored separately
        for i in range(nodes):
            if nodes <= 4:
                labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="Part "+str(i+1)))
                labels[-1].place(x=10+(120*i), y=55)
                textvars.append(tk.StringVar())
                textvars[-1].set("Change Ip")
                entries.append(tk.Entry(area, textvariable=textvars[-1]))
                entries[-1].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=80, width=100)
            else:
                labels.append(tk.Label(area, text="Node " + str(i + 1)))
                labels[-1].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=105)
                textvars.append(tk.StringVar())
                textvars[-1].set("Change Ip")
                entries.append(tk.Entry(area, textvariable=textvars[-1]))
                entries[-1].place(x=10 + (120 * i), y=160, width=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    """Calculate center of screen so popup is center"""
    w = 650
    h = 400

    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
    y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    # This line prevents the user from changing the size of the window
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable should by specified in Entry by textvariable and defined at the beginning using StringVar(), check the following code

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


root = Tk()
root.title("GUI titile")
root.geometry("200x100")


variable1 = StringVar()
variable2 = StringVar()

entry1 = Entry(root,textvariable=variable1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = Entry(root,textvariable=variable2)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

GUI output image :

[image: GUI output image]

## NOTE: imports differ according to python version